# How can I move top search div from left to right in header-wrapper in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, admin, frontend

I need to move top.search from right side to left side as per given in screenshot, I tried this below move element but this is not working

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="-" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your move tag using below code :

> **app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
    <body>
        <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="logo" />
    </body>  
</page>
```

Now, You need to update less code also :

```
.block-search {
    float: left;
}
```

Now, Just upgrade & deploy. You can see search will display to left side.

Comment: thank you for answer i miss the css part , it's work fine after apply css.